# Sorting by SUM very slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
  SELECT SUM(s.count) as count, a.name, s.author_id as id
    FROM twitter_author_daily_stats s
    JOIN twitter_author a ON s.author_id = a.id
   WHERE s.`date` >= '2011-01-07'
     AND s.`date` <= '2011-09-21'
     AND s.profile_twitter_search_id IN (263)
GROUP BY s.author_id
   LIMIT 30;
```

It uses an index (author_id, profile_twitter_search_id, date); it's fast (~1s); and it returns ~2500 rows.

However, when I add `ORDER BY count`, the query runs for minutes (I didn't bother waiting for it to finish).

Shouldn't it just take the ~2500 rows from original query and sort by `count` column? Why does it take so long?

Can someone who has better MySQL knowledge explain?

Comment: I think it would be better to group the result by `a.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Even better: get MySQL to explain it, with the aptly-named `EXPLAIN` keyword.

Optimisations with indexes can only be performed in [certain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) [situations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html), and changing ordering/grouping/conditions is a good way to alter the landscape quite considerably.

Comment: I've already done it and it's not very helpful. With ORDER BY it uses a temp table and a filesort. Without it it doesn't. Still it doesn't explain why it can't sort ~2500 rows in a reasonable time. Surely, creating a temp table of ~2500 rows and sorting it can't take that long. There's something weird happening internally which I don't understand.

Comment: @Pawel: It's _incredibly_ helpful. And there's nothing "weird" happening; you have merely failed to read through the documentation. Unless somehow you managed both sections to which I linked you in only 8 minutes, which seems unlikely. As I said, there's more to it than just sorting the result: that's not what your `ORDER BY` means.

Comment: I had read through those pages before I posted the question. I didn't find a solution. Are you saying there is a solution that I've missed?

Comment: @Pawel: Almost certainly. Without knowing your schema and your query plan and your data I couldn't tell you precisely what that is, and I probably wouldn't anyway! The information on optimising queries is all there so, now that you know `ORDER BY` behaving in this way isn't "weird", you can go ahead and read up about how it _does_ work.